# SurfaceView turns black when the activity resumes

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a SurfaceView in my activity, and it's hooked up to a MediaPlayer. The video runs fine when the activity is first created, but when I press the home button and then come back to the application, SurfaceView turns black and even the audio from the movie doesn't play.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mSurfaceView.getHolder().setFixedSize(1080, 1920);
    mSurfaceView.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mp == null)
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(this, video);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }

    mp.setLooping(true);

    //Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();

    lp.width = 1080;
    lp.height = 1920;

    //Commit the layout parameters
    mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    mp.setDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder());

    //Start video
    mp.start();
}
```

I looked into other solutions, but they were using custom classes that extends SurfaceView and implements Runnable. I wish to use the default SurfaceView class. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: What are u doing on SurfaceChanged and SurfaceDestroyed?

Comment: Nothing. Oh, could that be a problem?

Comment: See https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by pausing MediaPlayer when the activity gets paused.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mp.pause();
}
```